# Как средствами C# отправлять сообщения разным ботам в TELEGRAM?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Как средствами C# отправлять сообщения разным ботам в TELEGRAM?  Именно ботам так как отправлять сообщение юзерам или группам у меня получилось реализовать.

```
 //get user dialogs
        await client.ConnectAsync();
        var dialogs = (TLDialogsSlice) await client.GetUserDialogsAsync();

        //find channel by title
        var chat = dialogs.Users.Where(c => c.GetType() == typeof(TLUser)).Cast<TLUser>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Username == "Имя бота");

        //send message
        //   await client.SendMessageAsync(new TLInputPeerChannel() { UserlId = chat.Id, AccessHash = chat.AccessHash.Value }, "OUR_MESSAGE");
        //send message
        await client.SendMessageAsync(new TLInputPeerUser() { UserId = chat.Id }, "asdasd");
```

Comment: использовать разный `chat_id` например. Или в чем проблема, покажите код.

Comment: Я получаю все информацию о боте но не могу ему ничего отправить

Comment: @alexmail19Q бот не может инициировать общение пока ему  не напишут, а так как они оба боты, то круг замкнулся.

Answer (score 0):

у меня прокатила вот так))

```
var chat = dialogs.Users.Where(c => c.GetType() == typeof(TLUser)).Cast<TLUser>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Username == "имя бота или группы");
        BOT_ID = chat.Id;
        BOT_AccessHash = Convert.ToInt64(chat.AccessHash);
        await client.SendMessageAsync(new TLInputPeerUser() { UserId = BOT_ID, AccessHash = BOT_AccessHash }, "сообщение");
```